# Capistrano deployment of 2 apps at the same time without downtime

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

I have a shared library, which is, as its name stands for, a  project  shared between different projects to avoid DRY. The shared library is a GIT repository as well as the other apps (app1, app2, app3).

When deploying app1 I would like to first deploy shared and then app1. Same for app2 and app3. In order to avoid any downtime the shared library has to be deployed at the same time as the app1, so basically the deploy:symlink:release needs to happen at the end of both successful deployment.

When code changes in the shared library I have to make sure that all projects which rely on it are also deployed at the same time

I have so far successfully setup Capistrano to deploy each app separately. After some reading I am using now caphub but it doesn't seem to help me solving this issue.

What I am currently using:

```
namespace :app1 do
 task :deploy do
    run_locally do
       execute 'cap apps:shared staging deploy --dry-run', raise_on_non_zero_exit: true
       execute 'cap apps:app1 staging deploy --dry-run', raise_on_non_zero_exit: true
       execute 'cap apps:shared staging deploy', raise_on_non_zero_exit: true
       execute 'cap apps:app1 staging deploy', raise_on_non_zero_exit: true
    end
 end
end
```

The issue with execute is that app1 will be experiencing downtime while shared is updated and app1 is deploying.

What are the best practices to solve this issue? Is there a way to override capistrano's flow to only perform symlinks at the end of a task?

Comment: There is a new approach. Please see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40921589/2067375. ( Disclaimer : i am the owner of the gem )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While different people will answer differently, I think the "best practice" I would recommend is to have each project include the shared library within its deployment. Unless the code is massive or indeed must be deployed in tandem (such as changing shared configuration), there is usually very little downside to this. If you are using PHP, you can use Composer for this. With Ruby, Bundler. Both of these can point at a Git endpoint.

This is how Gems work in Capistrano, `Capistrano::Bundler` copies a unique, per-app copy of all of that app's gems into `shared/bundler`.

Edit:

To add a Composer shared library from a Git repository, you have two primary options:

1. Add a `composer.json` file to your library (this will make it easier/possible to do PSR-4 autoloading). Instructions here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories
2. Have Composer pull in your library blindly, just sticking it in `vendor/`. Instructions here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2

If you have a specific question regarding usage of Composer, I suggest you post a new question. Other people who are more familiar with Composer than I am will probably help you. I don't use Composer nearly as much as other tools.

Comment: As I mentioned the shared library is also a GIT repo. Is there a way to specify 2 GIT repositories in a capistrano's config file? Or how would you include the shared library within an app deployment?

Comment: You cannot deploy two git repos in one Capistrano configuration. To answer the second question, I have to ask: what language/framework is your app? Different systems use shared libs differently.

Comment: I am currently on a PHP + composer setup. The shared library is a mix of shared configurations and components.